# Cannot implicitly convert type (linq to entity)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-entities

I am working on  a mvc5 project and I connected my database with Linq to Entity but for some reasons I had to delete .edmx file and reconnect my databse in aother folder.

Since that time I am facing an error :

> "Cannot implicitly convert type 'TicketingDemoProject.Models.User' to
>   'TicketingDemoProject.User'.

I know the folder is not same but don't know how to reslove this issue.

Thank you for your help.

code :

```
    namespace TicketingDemoProject.Controllers{
public class TechnicianController : Controller{
private TicketingDBENtities tickets = new TicketingDBEntities();
public ActionResult Index(){
string username = User.Identity.name;
User u = tickets.User.Single(user1=>user1.user_name == username)
int userIdenti = u.User_Id;
}
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By changing the folder, you changed the namespace for your `edmx` generated classes. Visual studio by default will use the namespace based on the current folder name. You can modify your namespace for edmx to your previous one which is `TicketingDemoProject`.

To change the namespace:

- Right click on edmx file go to properties
- Specify Custom Tool Namespace *(Specify your new name space `TicketingDemoProject`)*. By default it would be empty, which means that it will have the default namespace generated by the visual studio based on the folder name.

[image]

Your code is using previously generated classes, which were in namespace `TicketingDemoProject` now since you changed the folder and generated `edmx` in `Model`, the namespace associated with the edmx's classes is `TicketingDemoProject.Models` and hence the error.

To see how Visual Studio manages the namespace see: [Understanding Visual Studio's Default Namespaces](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/VSNamespaces.aspx)

Comment: hello habib, thank you for your help, actuly i understood the cause of problem but I don't want to put it back into same folder. I want to keep the .edmx file into "Models" folder

Comment: @HarjinderRandhawa, just added instruction on how to change the namespace for edmx.

Comment: no. I am facing errors in other classes. I messed with my project. but fortunately i was working ofline with my dropbox. Going to recover the project from dropbox and keep it as backup. lol